# transition property in css not working when using hr

Tags: html, css

I'm learning `transitions` but I can't understand why my `hr` tags have no effect

```css
html {

  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;

}

body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  background-color: red;

}

hr {
  transition: width 1s;
  width: 5rem;
}

#container {
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 5rem;
  background-color: white;
  margin: auto;
}

#expand {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  transition: height 1s;
  text-align: center;
}

#expand:hover {
  height: 200px;
}

#expand:hover hr {
  width: 20rem;

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="container">
      <hr>
      <div id="expand">
        Learn More
      </div>
<hr>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your selector doesn't match; neither of your `hr` is a descendant of `div#expand`. The first one is a previous sibling (for which CSS has no selectors), whereas the 2nd one is an adjacent sibling (see my answer below).

`#expand:hover hr` targets any `hr` element that is a *descendant* of an element being hovered which has the `id="expand"`. The space between `#expand:hover` and `hr` is not meaningless in CSS; it's the `descendant selector`.

Given your current markup structure, the only `hr` you can target when `div#expand:hover` happens, is the one following it, using the `adjacent sibling combinator` `+`:

```css
html {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  background-color: red;
}

hr {
  transition: width 1s;
  width: 5rem;
}

#container {
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 5rem;
  background-color: white;
  margin: auto;
}

#expand {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  transition: height 1s;
  text-align: center;
}

#expand:hover {
  height: 200px;
}

#expand:hover+hr {
  width: 20rem;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <hr>
  <div id="expand">
    Learn More
  </div>
  <hr>
</div>
```

The rule is that **you can neither select backward nor upward from any given selector you've reached**.

Comment: is there any way I can expand the top hr as well?

Comment: Not with CSS as long as you keep the markup structure. It would have to be either a descendant or a sibling of `div#expand`.

Comment: You could sense the hover on container as both hrs are children of that.

Comment: @AHaworth That would be a functional change. Also that is an obvious option to anyone who reads and comprehends my answer.